# return content from S3 in Playframework 2.5 (scala)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

In Playframework 2.4.X I retorn content from S3 this:

```
  val s3Client = new AmazonS3Client()
  val s3doc = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key))
  val stream = s3doc.getObjectContent

  Ok.feed(Enumerator.fromStream(stream)).as(contentType)
```

But now in play 2.5 .feed is @deprecated("Use sendEntity with a Streamed entity instead"

I suppose that is something like this:

```
Ok.sendEntity(HttpEntity.Streamed(stream, None, None))
```

But I need transform stream to Source[ByteString, _]

How do I do this?

Comment: See my last edit to the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Assets controller has an "example"](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.0/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/controllers/Assets.scala#L391-L395) of how to do it. Basically, you need to do something like this:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import play.api.libs.streams.Streams

val stream = s3doc.getObjectContent
val data = Enumerator.fromStream(stream)

val source = Source.fromPublisher(Streams.enumeratorToPublisher(data)).map(ByteString.apply)
Ok.sendEntity(HttpEntity.Streamed(source, None, Some(contentType)))
```

**Edit:**

I didn't had time to test it, but after a better look at [Akka Stream source code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.4.2/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/StreamConverters.scala#L25-L42), maybe this is also a possible (and simpler) solution:

```
val stream = s3doc.getObjectContent
val source: Source[ByteString, _] = StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => stream)
Ok.sendEntity(HttpEntity.Streamed(source, None, Some("")))
```

Comment: Cannot write an instance of play.api.http.HttpEntity.Streamed to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[play.api.http.HttpEntity.Streamed]
[error]       Ok(HttpEntity.Streamed(source, Some(metadata.getContentLength), Some(metadata.getContentType)))
[error]         ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed

Comment: Ok, at both there were a `sendEntity` missing.

Comment: Be aware that if you do not provide `content-length` then content will be loaded into memory to calculate the `content-length` as stated in the play documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaStream#sending-large-amounts-of-data
In the question context, you can get the size of the object using the S3 API like this `s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getContentLength()`